# Identifier response is undefined and expected a ;

Tags: c++

In my c++ course, I have been asked to generate a random number between 1 and 12 and add it to a sum. The program will ask if the user wants to add another number with the input `y` or `n`, and if the input is `y` it will add another number. When the sum reaches 50, the program will automatically end.

However, on lines 14 and 27, I get the error:

> Expected a ;

And on line 16 I get the error:

> identifier response is undefined

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;
void rng(){
    int rng = ((rand() % 12) + 1);
    cout << rng;

}

int main()
{
    int sum = 0
        char response;
    cout << "Would you like to add a number? y or n";
    cin << response;

    while (response = 'y') {
        cout << "Would you like to add a number? y or n";
        cin << response;

        cout << "Okay then, the current sum is" << +" " << +sum << +rng;
        if (response = 'n')
            cout << "Okay thanks, have a good one";
        if (sum > 50)
            cout << "Alright the sum has reached 50 that seems like enough"
            break
    };
}
```

Comment: 1) `int sum = 0` is missing semicolon. 2) What should `<< +" " <<` mean?

Comment: Make sure you have a ``;`` at the end of every line. I can see several lines with them missing.

Comment: A few notes: `=` is assignment, `==` is equality. `cin << response` seems backwards, even just visually.  You're missing some semi-colons (and have one extra). Maybe take a step back, slow down a little, and look over your code one line at a time.

Comment: @user438383 Do note, that not ever line in C++ needs to end in a semicolon, but, rather - a statement. You could write entire program on a single line, with C++, but that doesn't mean, that you would need to write a single semicolon, while doing so.

Comment: Putting aside the snarkiness in some of the comments, those `+`s don't belong in the output statement. Also, in the output, you need to call `rng()`, not write out its address.

Comment: You definitely need to study harder, this course has not taught you everything you need to know.

Comment: Which line is 16? Could you not reduce your program to something simpler (a [mre]) to focus on the error? (The error to focus on is the first one reported by your compiler.) This sort of question should not require -- or even benefit from -- copying your assignment into the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of mistakes in your code - some related to syntax errors, and some related to logic issues.

Regarding the syntax errors:

- `int sum = 0`
  needs to be
  `int sum = 0;`
  A semicolon ends a statement.
- `cin << response;`
  needs to be
  `cin >> response;`
  `operator<<` is used for output, whereas `operator>>` is used for input.
- `cout << "Okay then, the current sum is" << +" " << +sum << +rng;`
  needs to be
  `cout << "Okay then, the current sum is " << sum;`
  Using `+` on `sum` is redundant, but using `+` on `rng` is just plain wrong, since `rng` is a function, not a variable.
- `cout << "Alright the sum has reached 50 that seems like enough"`
  needs to be
  `cout << "Alright the sum has reached 50 that seems like enough";`
  Again, a semicolon ends a statement.
- `break`
  needs to be
  `break;`
  Again, a semicolon ends a statement.

Regarding the logic issues:

- there is no need for `#include <iomanip>`, as you are not utilizing any stream manipulators.
- you are missing `#include <cstdlib>` for `rand()`.
- `rng()` is a function, but the statement `cout << ... << +sum << +rng;` is trying to print it out as if it were a variable instead.  The project requirement is to add the random number to the running sum, so `rng()` should `return` the number it generates, and then `main()` can add that number to `sum` before printing it out.
- you are not calling `srand()` to initialize the random number generator before calling `rand()` the 1st time.
- `while (response = 'y')` needs to be `while (response == 'y')`.  `operator=` is for assignment, `operator==` is for comparison.  That said, you should use a `do..while` loop instead, as there is no point in prompting the user twice on the 1st loop iteration.
- `if (response = 'n')` needs to be `if (response == 'n')`.  Again, assignment vs comparison.  Also, you are also not `break`'ing the loop if the user enters `'n'`.
- `if (sum > 50)` is missing `{}` braces, so the subsequent `break` is not part of the `if`, and thus it will be invoked unconditionally after the 1st loop iteration is done, so the user will never be able to enter more than 1 number.
- your `cout` statements should have `\n` or `std::endl` at the end of them, to print out a line break.

With that said, try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int rng(){
    return (rand() % 12) + 1;
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));

    int sum = 0;
    char response;

    do {
        cout << "Would you like to add a number? y or n: ";
        cin >> response;

        if (response == 'n') {
            cout << "Okay thanks, have a good one\n";
            break;
        }

        if (response == 'y') {
            sum += rng();
            cout << "Okay then, the current sum is " << sum << "\n";

            if (sum > 50) {
                cout << "Alright the sum has reached 50 that seems like enough\n";
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    while (true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
int sum = 0
```

Needs a semi-colon at the end.

Same with these lines:

```
cout << "Alright the sum has reached 50 that seems like enough"
break
```

You need to use `==` instead of `=` in the condition of the `while` statement:

```
while (response == 'y') {
```

Also, this line:

```
cout << "Okay then, the current sum is" << +" " << +sum << +rng;
```

should be

```
cout << "Okay then, the current sum is" << " " << sum << rng;
```